# Connecting with ORACLE

Tags: php

What are the most important conditions for a PHP connection with ORACLE?

I already wrote these extensions in PHP.ini and it did not work

```
extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
extension=php_oci8.dll
extension=php_oci8_12c.dll
extension=php_oracle.dll
extension=pdo_odbc
extension=pdo_pgsql
```

Code Used

```
    <?php

    $conn="(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.9)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = PRD)
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    )
    )";
    $conexao = oci_connect('DBA', '123', $conn);

    if (isset ($conexao) || empty($conexao)){
        $erro = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($erro['erro'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    exit;
    }

    echo"Hello";

?>
```

Errors

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\wamp64\www\Teste\testes\conexaooracle.php on line 12 

Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\wamp64\www\Teste\testes\conexaooracle.php on line 12
```

Comment: Please consider translating your post to English, *or*... posting to pt.stackoverflow.com, which is a Portuguese site.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is to install the Oracle client libraries.  If you don't have them on your machine, you can get these from [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html)

Once unzipped, set PATH environment variable to find them.

Only uncomment one of the `extension` lines to include OCI8. You probably just need

```
extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
```

This will actually work with 12c or later versions of Oracle Client libraries.

A useful PHP Oracle resource is the back half of http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html

P.S. you can simplify your connection to:

```
$conexao = oci_connect('DBA', '123', '192.168.0.9/PRD');
```